# Objective C, Can I generate UUID from a string?

Tags: objective-c

I know that I can do this in Java like

```
 UUID nodeId = UUID.fromString(eId.providerId);//eId.providerId returns a string
```

Can I do this in Objective c??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. There's a UUID type in Core Foundation, which has a [`CFUUIDCreateFromString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFUUIDCreateFromString) function, but there's almost nothing you can do with a `CFUUID` object.

So, the question is, why do you *want* an encapsulated version of your UUID? What do you want to do with it that you can't do with the string representation?

Comment: Surely the reasons for wanting an encapsulated object are obvious, it would prevent you from using an invalid uuid and prevent the need for all consumers of it to have to check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuuid/1411662-init

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Core Foundation's `CFUUID` functions.

[Here are Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html).